# How can i add google auto complete seach input in nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am working on a project in nuxt3 and I wanna add google places auto-complete on search input. I've been search for last 4 hours but can't got a way to set it up.

Comment: it would be better, if you can show, what you tried so far.

Comment: I solved it on my own after a very long research. There was no package available for nuxt3. it was difficult to show the code because there was no progress.

Comment: If you found a way, please post your own answer with those details (think about other devs who may have the same issue).

Comment: sure, I'll post it soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long research I found the below solution working for me in the nuxt3 stable version. 
  
**Install the following version (0.9.72) of @fawmi/vue-google-maps**  
*your package.json file:*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fawmi/vue-google-maps": "0.9.72",
}
```

*in nuxt.config.ts add following lines*

```
build: {
    transpile: ["@fawmi/vue-google-maps"],
},
```

*Then create folder named plugins and make a file inside it named vueGoogleMaps.ts*

```
plugins
 ┗ vueGoogleMaps.ts
```

*Your vueGoogleMaps.ts file:*

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import VueGoogleMaps from "@fawmi/vue-google-maps";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: "Your-key",
      libraries: "places", // This is required if you use the Autocomplete plugin
    },
    autobindAllEvents: true,
  });
});
```

*then in example.vue:*

```
<template>
  <GMapAutocomplete
       placeholder="This is a placeholder"
       @place_changed="setPlace"
    >
  </GMapAutocomplete>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPlace() {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me hours of back and forth :)